# In Angular, with ViewChild/ ViewChildren, how do I get the child of a child?

Tags: angular

```
@ViewChildren(Subcomponent) sComp;
```

Will get me the Subcomponent children of my current component, but I want to get the values of elements that are children of Subcomponent. How do I do that?

Comment: You want to see the grand children of your own components or third party ones?

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet of what you have tried for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

In `Subcomponent` you can have a method defined to return it's child:

```
@ViewChildren(ChildA) childAOfSubcomponent;

getChildA() {
  return this.childAOfSubcomponent;
}
```

Now in current component use this:

```
this.sComp.getChildA();  // thi will return child of SubComponent
```

Comment: Note that this will work only if you can modify these components. Won't work for third part ones.

Comment: @adisplayname, can you Please accept the answer if it helped